# How do I create 2 btn-group on same page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. I am having 2 btn-group on same page. Each of them working fine but when I click on one it unselect (remove active class?) the other.
How can I keep the active class?

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="focusarea" class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-territory="pays">Pays</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-territory="dept">Département</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-territory="ville">Ville</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="foc" class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-territory="pays">Pays</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-territory="dept">Département</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-territory="ville">Ville</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it removes the focus from the other group, you are focussing on something new, so focus shifts.

Comment: just a copypast error sorry. I don't have 2 id with same name on my page.

Comment: so should i create a "custom-active" class and create a jquery addClass removeClass rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add classess dynamically using Jquery, use .addClass() and .removeClass() Check [JqueryAPI](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) for more info.

I tried to replicate your requirement check [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/11571/):

```
$('#foc').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#foc .btn").click(function(){
$("#foc .btn").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});

$("#focusarea .btn").click(function(){
$("#focusarea .btn").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```